# How to be able to edit and delete the content inside a card? Laravel - vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm making a discussion forum with comments and replies, I used to display them in a table but I've changed and am now using cards to display them, like so: 
[image]

This was I can display correctly the replies, however now I'm not sure how I would delete or edit the comments the user has made, or reply to other comments. To note I'm not displaying the reply button but there would be one on the parent comment, I'm not sure how I would write the logic for a reply to a reply.

This is the functional vue.js code for deleting a table row, editing a table row and replying. I'm using dialogs to get the user input.

```
openReply(row) {
    this.dialogReplyVisible = true;
    this.parent = row;
},
edit(model) {
    this.mode = 'Editar';
    this.form = _.cloneDeep(model);
    this.dialogFormVisible = true;
},
remove(row) {
    this.$confirm('Desea borrar este Comentario? Esto es permanente.',
        'Advertencia', {
            confirmButtonText: 'Si',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            cancelButtonClass: 'el-button--info',
            confirmButtonClass: 'el-button--warning',
            type: 'warning'
        }).then(() => {
        this.loading = true;
        this.$inertia.delete(this.baseUrl + '/' + row.id)
            .then(
                () => {
                    this.$message({
                        type: 'success',
                        message: 'Eliminado correctamente.'
                    });

                    this.comments = this.$page.comments;
                    this.loading = false
                },
                (res) => {
                    this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            )
    })
},
```

The routes on the web.php

```
Route::post('comments/update/{id}', 'ReplyController@update');
Route::post('comments/reply', 'ReplyController@replyStore');
Route::post('comments/reply/update/{id}', 'ReplyController@replyUpdate');
Route::resource('comments', 'ReplyController'); //this does the store and delete
```

These are the buttons where these methods get called

```
<div class="btn-link-edit action-button"
    @click="edit(scope.row)">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
</div>
<div class="btn-link-delete action-button"
    @click="remove(scope.row)">
    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</div>
<div class="btn-link-preview action-button"
    @click="openReply(scope.row)">
    <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
</div>
```

Other relevant data is the form its trying to clone and the base urls

```
form: {
    comment: '',
},
replyForm: {
    comment: '',
},
baseUrl: '/comments',
customUpdateUrl: '/comments/update',
```

So my final question is how to change those edit, delete and reply functions to get it to work with cards instead of a table.

> EDIT: I got the remove function working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself is still good I just needed to change with I sent though as the parameter. I didn't know that the `model` it was asking for is basically just an object, so I just send through the object I wanted for the edit and reply and for the remove I just passed the id through and changed the post url from

```
 this.$inertia.delete(this.baseUrl + '/' + row.id)
```

to

```
 this.$inertia.delete(this.baseUrl + '/' + id)
```

I could've just sent the object through as well, as it would've taken the id when sending it anyway.

The button with the new parameters

```
<div class="btn-link-preview action-button"
    @click="openReply(comment)">
    <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
</div>
<div class="btn-link-edit action-button"
    @click="edit(comment)">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
</div>
<div class="btn-link-delete action-button"
    @click="remove(comment.id)">
    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</div>
```

This is what is inside `comment` without replies, and the object I send though

```
{ 
   "id":8,
   "user_id":24,
   "discussion_forum_id":1,
   "parent_id":null,
   "comment":"adsfadsfasdf",
   "comment_time":"2019-12-03 14:55:09",
   "created_at":null,
   "updated_at":null,
   "user":{ 
      "id":24,
      "name":"Vinny Ridley",
      "card":"12353",
      "scard":"97524",
      "user_type_id":4,
      "email":"v@email.com",
      "created_at":"2019-12-02 13:07:37",
      "updated_at":"2019-12-02 13:07:37"
   },
   "replies":[ 

   ]
}
```

For editing and deleting a reply I just send `reply` or `reply.id` and that does it. Hope this helps someone with the same or similar issue.